# CSS not being override position:relative by position:static

Tags: html, css, position

I have some bootstrap styling applying a position:relative on an outer DOM. I have a tooltip with absolute positioning so I don't want the position: relative on this outer DOM element.

However if I deselect the position: relative in the styles inspector then I can get the required functionality. The tooltip absolute positions in the correct area.

So I added a position: static to override the position: relative. Even with !important this has no effect.

Any ideas appreciated.

Video: http://screencast.com/t/IWvGSuXUDG

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-4 client_col">{LIST ITEMS}</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-md-4 {
    position: relative;
}
.client_col, .col-md-4.client_col {
    position: static;
}
```

Comment: Nice movie. But you need to put a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Added code example

Comment: Well that sure is minimal, but that's not complete nor verifiable.

Comment: Unsure how to make more complete and verfiable when it is a full site pulling css from seperate files...

Comment: If you have to include the entire site, you have to include the entire site. What you've given us will be `static` at all times. You might wanna just call it up in Firebug or chrome's dev tools (hit F12), and check what styles are applying.

Comment: Correction. It's got a class `class=` applied to it, and I've never seen bool attributes `col-md-4` and `client_col` before, and you've got an extraneous `"`. Dat typo.

Comment: class=" was a typo - fixed - apologies

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the html class="class="

and the stlyes what you see are inherit